# What response should be sent to device after the SCEP payload?

Tags: iphone, ios, mdm

I have sent the SCEP payload to the iOS device, and I got the reply from the device too.Now I am getting the response as GetCACert something like that.
Now what response have to be sent to the device ? Whether I need to send any certificate from the device ? I tried by sending some certificates which is self signed,but I am getting error as SCEP Server Configuration is not supported. Please help me.
I am really struck here

Comment: Can you post a bit more about the code you've posted? Where is the error being displayed?

Comment: After getting the device attributes from device, I am sending the profile to the device which consists of SCEP payload to the device. The device is sending back the response as GET which is GetCACert.

Comment: It sounds like you are sending your MDM URL as the SCEP URL which is why it is trying to get the CA cert (the first step in a SCEP provisioning). Check that the SCEP URL is really pointing at your SCEP server.

Comment: Ya, I have given the MDM URL and SCEP URL as same, I figured this one week back. Now I have changed the url and the Certificate is issued. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Cyril, if I need to use OTA enrollment then to make the device aware of SCEP URL do I need to add SCEP payload configured in enrollment profile?

Comment: @Manmay . You dont' need to add the SCEP payload in the enrollment profile. After the device sending response to the enrollment profile, you should send the SCEP payload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya, I have given the MDM URL and SCEP URL as same, I figured this one week back. Now I have changed the url and the Certificate is issued. Thank you